# What defines a separate visit when getting beverage container recycling refunds on a per-container basis instead of by weight?

Tags: united-states, california, currency, environmental

I read on http://www.calrecycle.ca.gov/BevContainer/Consumers/CashingIn.htm ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180105211444/http://www.calrecycle.ca.gov/BevContainer/Consumers/CashingIn.htm)), regarding  getting beverage container recycling refunds on a per-container basis instead of by weight in California:

> By law, you can bring up to 50 aluminum, 50 glass, 50 plastic, and 50 bi-metal California Redemption Value (CRV) containers in a single visit and request to be paid by count. You will be paid the full CRV redemption of 5 cents or 10 cents on each container. Inform the site attendant of your load content and how you would like to receive payment before you hand over your load.

What defines a separate visit? E.g., if I enter the recycling center, cash out 50 aluminum cans, go outside the store, and enter again to cash 50 more aluminum cans, does that count as a new visit?

Answer (score 1):

The [reasonableness test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_person) defines a seperate visit.